# Building multi word LIKE Prepared statement for PDO query

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to build the logic to create a multi word LIKE statement for use with PDO.

This takes the search string $str to build the multiple parts of the LIKE section:

```
$str = $_POST['str'];

$keywords = preg_split('/[\s]+/', $str);
$totalKeywords = count($keywords);

$search = "%$str%";
$sql_str = " AND post_content LIKE :search0 ";

for($i=1 ; $i < $totalKeywords; $i++){
    $search_bit = ":search" . $i;
    $sql_str .= " AND post_content LIKE $search_bit ";
}
```

This is the SQL statement - with the $sql_str slotted into the correct point:

```
$sql = "SELECT d.ID
             , d.post_date
             , d.post_content
             , d.post_cat_id
             , d.post_label
             , c.fld_cat
          FROM tbl_log_days d
             , tbl_log_cats c
         WHERE d.post_cat_id = c.fld_id " . $sql_str . "
      ORDER BY post_date";
```

Then for binding the variables, I have tried two approaches:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

if (!empty($sql_str)) {

    foreach ($keywords as $key => &$keyword){
        $foo = '%'.$keyword.'%';
        $stmt->bindParam(':search' . $key, $foo);
    }

}
```

And also this (without the ampersand before the $keyword in the foreach line):

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

if (!empty($sql_str)) {

    foreach ($keywords as $key => $keyword){
        $foo = '%'.$keyword.'%';
        $stmt->bindParam(':search' . $key, $foo);
    }

}
```

However, when I search for e.g. "past hill" and check the resulting SQL that is actually run (I enabled query logging in MySQL), it only takes the last word in the search string:

```
SELECT d.ID
     , d.post_date
     , d.post_content
     , d.post_cat_id
     , d.post_label
     , c.fld_cat
  FROM tbl_log_days d
     , tbl_log_cats c
 WHERE d.post_cat_id = c.fld_id  AND post_content LIKE '%past%'  AND post_content LIKE '%past%' 
  ORDER BY post_date
```

I have done a var_dump of the $keyword variable when running a search and it returns:

```
string(4) "hill"
string(4) "past"
```

I can't work this one out. Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the same question on Sitepoint:
https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/multi-word-like-prepared-statement-for-pdo-query/223738/5

And got a solution there:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
if (!empty($sql_str)) {
    for ($x = 0; $x<$totalKeywords; $x++) {
    // add the percent signs, or make a new copy of the array first if you want to keep the parameters
    $keywords[$x] = "%" . $keywords[$x] . "%";  
    $stmt->bindParam(':search' . $x, $keywords[$x]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this

```
for($i=1 ; $i < $totalKeywords; $i++){
  $search_num = "search" . $i;
  $search_bit = ":" . $search_num;
  $sql_str .= " AND post_content LIKE $search_bit ";
    $foo = '%'.$keyword.'%';
  $V[$search_bit] = $foo;
}

$query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$query->execute($V);
```

(I haven't tested this code, so please excuse typos.)